# Software to translate text entered in Chrome browser from English to Russian in real-time

Tags: chrome, translation, real-time

Let's say you want to chat with a Russian who doesn't know English, but you don't want to copy and paste text into a translator for every message.

**How do you translate the English text as you type, or at the end of typing (manually and/or automatically) to Russian?** Preferably WITHOUT HASSLES.

I want to achieve this on Chrome browser.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] and rewrite your question explicitly asking for software (and not "How do I"), otherwise it is off-topc for this site. Read the [help].

Comment: So you want a Chrome extension that works on any input on any page that translates English to Russian as you type, or as soon as you finish typing?

Comment: Are you open to any chatting webapp? Would an extension that shows a translation whenever your mouse hover on a sentence be OK?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ yes, that is correct! that's what i want.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul well actually i am trying to translate from vk.com, but it would be good if it worked with every website.

Comment: @TonyTCG there was an 'or' in my question - which one is it?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ ohh, okay sorry, didnt notice it... well, it would be good to translate as soon as it finishes typing, and also allow for manual editing after... but mainly, it should translate as you type, and also allow for manual editing of the words as you go. 

I know it's too much, but I think someone has done something like this, if not, then, this is a great idea.